# The material textures on Unity WebGL are very blurry than on editor/builds

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, unity-webgl

I have made my game and I am currently testing it. I have discovered that the textures in the WebGL build are blurry and it obviously does not look good
Here's a comparison:

Editor Image
[image: WebGL Image]

WebGL Image
[image: Editor Image]

I have tried changing the setting of the sprites but it does not change anything (that I can notice and would solve my problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a list of a few solutions that could help

- Disable mipmapping on your textures
- Change the texture quality of your project for WebGL, which should be under **Edit > Player Settings > Quality**. I believe it defaults to `Very Low`
- Change the filter mode of the texture to `Point`

How large is the current texture you are using?

Comment: @AshmeetSIngh It should be under `Advanced` and the specific field is is `Generate Mip Maps`. Toggling that off should help.

Comment: I actually did not write the full one it sent the half I click enter by mistake
this is what I wanted to type after that
-Changing the quality of the texture worked for me 
My texture is of 512x512 pixels - Thinking about it now I think it is large should I reduce its size? to maybe 256x256  or 100x100 or something else - If you wanted the other size then its 9 kb as my laptop is saying...its just 2 straight white lines on a black background - it helped for the boxes of the levels

Comment: Thanks for helping me out...It is very very helpful for me

Comment: @AshmeetSIngh The larger the texture, the more detail you will get. As your texture is rather simple, you can try to downscale it and see how it looks. Larger textures take up more space, so it is finding a good balance between efficiency and usability. If this post answered your question, would you mind clicking on the checkmark to the left of the post? It closes the question and lets others know it has an answer that solves the issue.